# How to create a Verification Key for my web Service from android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

in my current android app I need a key which is special to my App and hackers can't reach it , and I can verify that in each API call , is there any app specific key or way of creating one that is safe for using?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent hackers completely as there's always a way they exploit your but you can use this prevent calls this way so authorized user action will be more secure

Create hash with each login of user, and save that in database and in shared preference in the application, for every further call send hash to API and check against the database to check if user is authorized to call the API

Here's an example how you can create hash

Put this into your "Utils" class.

```
public static String getSha256Hash(String password) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = null;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        digest.reset();
        return bin2hex(digest.digest(password.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}

private static String bin2hex(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(data.length * 2);
    for (byte b : data)
        hex.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xFF));
    return hex.toString();
}

public static String getCurrentTimeStamp(){
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormat.format(new Date()); // Find todays date

        return currentDateTime;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }

public static String random() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    StringBuilder randomStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int randomLength = generator.nextInt(MAX_LENGTH);
    char tempChar;
    for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++){
        tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
        randomStringBuilder.append(tempChar);
    }
    return randomStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Example of use:

```
String token =  Utils.getSha256Hash(getCurrentTimeStamp()+username+random())
```

Comment: thanks man , but the thing is if hackers can get access to shared preference , this would be worthless , I need a key that is so much harder for them to get , something related to android .

Comment: Shared preference is not accessible by anyone other than system and app itself, a key cannot be your solution in this case, key needs to be store anywhere, add more validation on your sever like saving device id to check if user is calling the api from same URL, nothing can be hack proof neither a key can protect, security depends on how you store data and how you are creating your APIs, look for more specific things than key